# Create tables automatically with PDI blueprints

Tags: java, pentaho, pdi

i´m trying to run the included example in blueprints to auto create table and i have a error. I can´t get it to work.

The example of PDI blueprint: https://github.com/mattcasters/blueprints
I have the setup ok but when i run "create-all-tables.ktr" get this error:  Unexpected error : org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "quoteField" of null (trans_End#8) .
The problem is the step javascript with the function  "valueMeta.setName( dbMeta.quoteField(name)" .
I would be very grateful for any help .

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLNUE.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEF7c.png)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yfHe.png)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

finally i fix the problem !!! The problem was that the transformation did not save the database connection because the database connection  it was not used . The solution has been easy , i have created a step in the transformation that uses the database connection. Then, when run the tranformation not crash y run correctly.
Best regards !!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAVzk.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).